# Crop an image using OpenCV Coordinates

Tags: python, opencv

I have the coordinates values of an image as:

```
tl = (result['topleft']['x'], result['topleft']['y'])
br = (result['bottomright']['x'], result['bottomright']['y'])
```

I would like to crop the original image (of sizes [720,720,3]) around that area of interest; what is the correct formula?

I have found this one:

```
crop_img = imgcv[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

But I struggle to put the right values of the coordinate system in it;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`crop_img = imgcv[y:y+h, x:x+w]` is a correct formula to do it if you have a rectangle, i.e. the top left point and the width and height of the rectangle, but you can do it directly since you have the top left and bottom right points.

```
crop_img = imgcv[tl[1]:br[1], tl[0]:br[0]]
```

basically the formula tells `from:to` first in y coordinates and then in x coordinates. Since the top left point of the image is the origin, then its coordinates is the `from` and the bottom right coordinates is the `to`

If you have any doubt, leave a comment